# Map each row of a dataframe to multiple rows in another dataframe

Tags: r

Each rownames(cpg.sig.data) may match to more than one `meth.anno$genesUniq` value. If so, take the average row values in cpg.sig.data.
My code did not take the average of rows where rownames(cpg.sig.data) match to multiple `meth.anno$genesUniq` values.

```
tmp <- meth.anno |> left_join(tibble::rownames_to_column(cpg.sig.data, var = "probeID")) |> summarize(across(where(is.numeric), mean), .by = c(probeID, genesUniq))
tmp <- tmp[!is.na(tmp$genesUniq),]
sig.data$meth_logFC <- tmp$logFC
sig.data$meth_PValue <- tmp$P.Value
```

Traceback:

```
> sig.data$meth_logFC <- tmp$logFC
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, meth_logFC, value = c(-0.012476936963993,  : 
  replacement has 49559 rows, data has 48
```

Input:

```
> dput(meth.anno[1:5,5:6])
structure(list(probeID = c("cg07582955", "cg10984178", "cg22109675", 
"cg05776004", "cg07700843"), genesUniq = c("KLHL17", "ISG15", 
"MXRA8", "PRKCZ", "KLHL17")), row.names = c(210L, 316L, 1071L, 
2095L, 2625L), class = "data.frame")

> dput(cpg.sig.data[1:5,])
structure(list(logFC = c(-1.33726222012845, -1.40897563016444, 
-1.38798168265872, -1.21923103450435, 1.38644488863777), AveExpr = c(-2.13707976814681, 
-1.45926977655276, -1.31354417875144, 2.28829856676417, 1.59047727951378
), t = c(-3.64265357213003, -3.59525574797294, -3.39710927903077, 
-3.39372719019887, 3.29575429593522), P.Value = c(0.000197549688272703, 
0.000233267278871743, 0.000458741877325374, 0.000463231735114995, 
0.000641798390297788), adj.P.Val = c(0.999999999999996, 0.999999999999996, 
0.999999999999996, 0.999999999999996, 0.999999999999996)), row.names = c("cg26472441", 
"cg04144611", "cg10984178", "cg10984178", "cg07582955"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: The code works fine on the sample data you've provided. But in the sample data `rownames(cpg.sig.data)` matches to only single `meth.anno$genesUniq` values If the issue arises when there are multiple matches, please provide sample data with multiple matches to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: I've updated the example. Thank you

Comment: Re-ran the code on the updated example. I get no errors and the result looks as expected.

Comment: What is the point of the last three lines that cause the error? `tmp <- tmp[!is.na(tmp$genesUniq),]` pulls the `genesUniq` for 3 of the 5 rows (the rows with missing values), then `sig.data$meth_logFC <- tmp$logFC` tries to assign those 3 values to the 5-row data frame. 5 != 3, so this is an error. *"My code did not take the average of rows where rownames(cpg.sig.data) match to multiple meth.anno$genesUniq values."* This is incorrect, the duplicate rows are averaged.